# Undo mark as merged

Tags: eclipse, svn

I am using Eclipse Indigo and subeclipse as the svn plugin for eclipse. Now here is the situation. I was synchronizing my project with the remote repository. There were conflicts present and I mistakenly clicked on "mark as merged" for one of the files without merging it. I tried restarting eclipse and some other stupid hacks. But nothing works out. So is there a way to undo "mark as merged" action?

Comment: what happens when you synchronize again?

Comment: Simplest solution: copy the file elsewhere, revert to your working copy base, then copy the file back.

Comment: @Eli if after reverting I copy my file back its just showing my outgoing changes and not thee incoming changes.

Comment: @sahil I tried that..its not working as the file is marked as merged.So it does not show any conflicts

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29949644/2961878
         This is not answer to your question, but I think AZURITE is an awesome Eclipse plugin which may help you in future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mark as Merged means that the local version of the file contains the content you want, after having compared the files and manually resolving issues.  Subclipse still has to update the local file so that SVN's metadata is happy, so it saves the current content of the file, runs svn update, and then replaces the file.

So you can now run Team > Revert if you want the file to match what was in the repository, or Compare with > Base Revision if you just want to examine the differences again and possibly make more changes.

Comment: Yeah...this is the method I followed but it would have been great if you could undo the process. I also tried finding the flag in the svn meta data to undo the process. But no success.

Comment: Well, you cannot really undo an svn update, other than to use update again and specify an older revision number.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of Marks suggestions worked for me.  The class did revert back to the original (pre-merged) state, but trying to Merge again just gave me a 'no differences detected' message.

What did end up working for me was to Compare With > Local History.  I was able to pick a version that was right before I hit Mark As Merged, and that got me back to the Compare Editor view that I had during the original Merge (which showed all the conflicts).  I was then able to change the code correctly, and Mark As Merged again.

Answer (score -1):

Delete the local project and re-import it, and this has the effect of undoing an accidental 'Mark as Merged' action.  Just make sure that the deletion won't result in loss of uncommitted work.